# How many times field has recurred in a list

Tags: apex

i have an account A1 and contact c1, c3, c3 as related list. Contact has name like

C1- Ravi
C2 - Ravi
C3 - Sunny

I want to know how i can get how many times "Ravi" has occured.

```
trigger WOServiceTrigger on Work_Order_Item__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    List<Work_Order__c> wo = new List<Work_Order__c>();
    List<Work_Order_Item__c> woi1 = new List<Work_Order_Item__c>();
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

    Map<String, Integer> parentToHighest = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, String> parentToValue = new Map<String, String>();

    for(Work_Order_Item__c woi:trigger.new){

        ids.add(woi.Work_Order__c);
    }

    woi1=[select id,Work_Order__c,Work_Order__r.Account__c,Service__c from Work_Order_Item__c where Work_Order__c=:ids];

    for(AggregateResult ar:[select count(Id) num, Service__c, Work_Order__c from Work_Order_Item__c where Work_Order__c in : ids group by Work_Order__c, Service__c]){

        Integer num = (Integer)ar.get('num');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+num);
        String name = (String)ar.get('Work_Order__c');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+name);
        String type = (String)ar.get('Service__c');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+type);


        if(parentToHighest.get(type) == null || parentToHighest.get(type) < num)
    {
        parentToHighest.put(type, num);
        parentToValue.put(type, type);
    }

    }


}
```

Regards

Comment: What you tries so far?

Comment: I have updated my trigger. I want to know how many times the value in Service__c field has recurred.

Comment: So can you tell us what is not working currently? What are you expecting out of the code, and what is the current result?

Comment: Work_Order_Item__c is a related list to Work_Order__c. In Work_Order_Item__c there is field Service__c. Suppose there are 5 Work_Order_Item__c  records and Service__c field is having value as w1,w1, w2, w3, w4. w1 value should get updtaed in custom field in Work_Order__c object. I need to check how frequently the values are reoccuring. The highest occured value should get upfated in Work_Order__c  object..

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) example.

Create Map, when you will iterate through your list - populate map with order.name -> order.name, sum.

Class wrapperOrder:

```
global class wrapperOrder implements Comparable{
    public string name;
    public integer sum;

    public wrapperOrder(string name, integer sum) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        wrapperOrder compareToEmp = (wrapperOrder)compareTo;
        if (sum == compareToEmp.sum) return 0;
        if (sum > compareToEmp.sum) return 1;
        return -1;        
    }
}
```

Map population:

```
List<Work_Order_Item__c> woiList = new List<Work_Order_Item__c> ();
woiList.add(new Work_Order_Item__c(Service__c = 'berlin'));
woiList.add(new Work_Order_Item__c(Service__c = 'paris'));
woiList.add(new Work_Order_Item__c(Service__c = 'london'));
woiList.add(new Work_Order_Item__c(Service__c = 'berlin'));
map<String,wrapperOrder> workOrderNameToSumMap = new map<String,wrapperOrder>();
for (Work_Order_Item__c woi :woiList){
    if (workOrderNameToSumMap.containsKey(woi.Service__c ) ){
        workOrderNameToSumMap.get(woi.Service__c).sum += 1;
    } else {
        workOrderNameToSumMap.put(woi.Service__c, new wrapperOrder( woi.Service__c, 1));
    }
}
workOrderNameToSumMap.values().sort();
system.debug( workOrderNameToSumMap.values()[0] );

//|DEBUG|wrapperOrder:[name=berlin, sum=3]
```

Comment: Hi llya thanks for the help. I will try this .. But in your debug log berlin should come 2 times not 3 rt??

Comment: Yes, it should be 2, I've removed insufficient items before pasting answer.